# Get the third property from selected row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which is the best way to get a table row element? 
I have this grid, it is a dynamically added grid. Every `td` has the class='dxgv'

[image]

The first column is a selectable column, which contains the id of the row, but I need to know in the client side also the third property from the selected row. (Prejudicii, Penalitati....)

I thought that I can do something like this:

```
 var td = $(".dxgv").find("td:eq(3)").val();
```

and I will get the value, but it is not working.

I have tried the answers, but I could not resolve the problem.
For example if I use

```
 var ee = $('tr:has(input:checked) td:eq(3)').text();
 var td = $(".dxgv:eq(2)").text();
 console.log('Textbox value at row ' + i + ': ' + td);
 console.log('ee value at row ' + i + ': ' + ee);
```

I get this: 
[image]

Comment: It is unclear in your question how is the page formatted, and what ever is triggering the logic that fetches the text. Please update your question to include the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly right, but there are some small things wrong:

1) `.find()` gets elements which are children of the selection. Your tds *are* the selection, and have no children, so this will not locate anything. Instead you need to select the 3rd element directly from the collection

2) `.val()` gets values from form fields such as textboxes. To get the value from a non-form element such as a td, you need to use `.text()`.

3) `eq()` uses zero-indexing, so to get the 3rd element you actually need to ask for element `2`.

```js
$(function() {
  var td = $(".dxgv:eq(2)").text();
  console.log(td);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="dxgv">1st</td>
    <td class="dxgv">2nd</td>
    <td class="dxgv">3rd</td>
    <td class="dxgv">4th</td>
    <td class="dxgv">5th</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have edited the question, can you please take a look.

Comment: @Kar when and where are you running the code to print those console values? As you can see from the runnable snippet in my answer, the code I've used does work. Context is everything...perhaps you are running this code before your table rows are created, or something?

Answer (score 2):

Your JQuery logic is a little bit off, but almost there.

```
 var td = $(".dxgv").find("td:eq(3)").val();
```

The above snippet you are using tells the browser to look for the third `<td>` element inside an element with the class `.dxgv`. But based on the screenshot you've provided, the problem is apparent:

- it is the `<td>` itself has the class
- the cell is the third cell (index of `2`, not `3`)

So what you want is to use this selector:

```
var td = $(".dxgv").eq(2).text();
```

The changes:

- Use `.eq(2)` to filter through the current selection, so that you get the third `.dxgv` element. Remember that JS uses a **zero-based** index (third element has index of `2`)
- Use `.text()` to access the textual content of the element

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var td = $('.dxgv').eq(2).text();
  console.log(td);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="dxgv"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
   <td class="dxgv">24/04/2018</td>
   <td class="dxgv">Prejudicii</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button">Click to get text from third cell</button>
```

Comment: I have edited the question, can you please take a look.

Comment: @Kar If you don't share your markup and create an MCVE, there's really nothing much we can help. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some kind of input element, `.val()` will not work. You can use `.html()` or `.text()` instead:

```
var td = $(".dxgv").eq(2).text(); // note .eq(2), because the function is zero-based.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because jQuery's `find()` looks **inside** the element you have already selected. Hence, the code you have given looks for the fourth (the index of the first element is 0) `td` inside every `.dxgv`, which does not exist. 
Additionally, seeing as it is not an `input` element, you need the text inside rather than its value.

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
$('tr:has(input:checked) td:eq(2)').text();
```

This selects every `tr` that has a checked `input` inside of it, then selects the third `td` from it.

Do note that `text()` gets the text from every element that is matched and just combines them into a single String, so if you want to support the selection of multiple rows, you will need to use jQuery's [forEach()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function to add them to an Array one by one.

Comment: .val() will not return anything, because a td is not a form element. See all the other answers already posted...

Comment: @ADyson fair point, I updated my answer accordingly. For some reason, I did not see the other answers coming in as I was writing mine.

Comment: No problem. Looks good now. Have an upvote for including a restriction to searching within the rows with a ticked checkbox, which no-one else has mentioned.